# target="_blank" doesn't work in tabs created with Tabs API in Firefox Add-On SDK

Tags: html, hyperlink, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

Opening tab with

```
require("sdk/tabs").open({
  url:require("sdk/self").data.url("demo.html")
});
```

`demo.html` contains this element:

```
<a target="_blank" href="https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/tabs">click me</a>
```

The `target` attribute is not honored, the page opens in the same tab and of course is subjected to all attach events on the tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would comment but don't have enough reputation.

I just set up fresh firefox addon repo using cfx init to test this out, and in my case, it did open the link in a new tab.

Here is the code.

main.js

```
require("sdk/tabs").open({
  url:require("sdk/self").data.url("demo.html")
});
```

and demo.html:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<p>Hello!</p>
<a target="_blank" href="https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/tabs">click me</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hmm, copied, compiled, still wrong result.  Must be a linux thing, or maybe an about:config thing.  Thanks nevertheless.

Comment: Hmm. I'm clutching at straws, but it may be a browser setting. EDIT: I say some stupid things sometimes.

Comment: So I looked in the about:config settings. If I set "browser.link.open_newwindow" to 1, then the target is not honoured. However, in my case, the default setting when using `cfx run` is 3, and not 1. You don't mention how you are running your addon, so i'm assuming it's `cfx run`, and thus this probably won't help.